# Lego arrangement function limit comparison

Tags: combinatorics

Let L(x) be the equation that gives us [the number of possible arrangements of x Legos](http://www.math.ku.dk/~eilers/lego.html)—L(2)=24, L(3)=1560, L(6)=915,103,765, etc..

I think that this might be true:
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{L\left(x+1\right)}{L\left(x\right)} \approx 100 $$

Can someone prove this to be true or false?

Comment: If they could (*prove it true or false*), then it would be worthy of writing a paper on.  [A paper linked to in your link](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0504039.pdf) discusses the problem and gives upper and lower bound estimates on the rate of growth being between $78.32$ and $191.35$.

Comment: It is worth reading a more recent paper [found here](http://www.math.ku.dk/~eilers/papers/eclbii.pdf) which goes further and generalizes the problem to bricks of arbitrary length/width.  One of the authors was cited in the previously linked article while the other author was also an author on the previously linked article.  There, they make the claim that a more accurate estimate would be 117.  Also of interest is the [oeis](http://oeis.org/A112389) entry for this problem where they now have nine entries of the sequence calculated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what is meant by "$\approx$" in the question but the status of this question is:

1. I don't think there is any way to disprove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{L(n+1)}{L(n)}=100$ **exactly** (although I find that highly unlikely).
2. It is unknown if $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{L(n+1)}{L(n)}$ exists.
3. It is known that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[n]{L(n)}$ exists and is in the interval $[78,192]$.
4. **If** $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{L(n+1)}{L(n)}$ exists, it must hence also be in this interval.

Comment: It was quite a while ago that I asked this, but I think I was just trying to find a pattern to $L(n+1) / L(n)$, and it seemed that it was closing in on 100---but that was just a guess