# Number of ways to stack LEGO bricks

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, recreational-mathematics, discrete-geometry, statistical-mechanics

One of the most surprising combinatorial formulas I know of counts the number of LEGO towers built from $n$ "$1 \times 2$" blocks subject to four rules:

1. The bricks lie in a single plane.
2. Each brick is offset by 1 stud (as in a brick wall).
3. The bottom layer is contiguous.
4. Each brick has at least one brick below it (apart from the bottom layer).

## Example

[image: Example of a]

## Formula

On page 26 of [Miklós Bóna's *Handbook of Enumerative Combinatorics*](https://books.google.com/books?id=j3kZBwAAQBAJ), the author states the combinatorial formula (!!):

> Remarkably there are $3^{n-1}$ domino towers consisting of $n$ bricks. Equally remarkably, no simple bijection is known.

The formula was first proven in 1988 by [Gouyou-Beauchamps and Viennot](https://doi.org/10.1016/0196-8858(88)90017-6).

## Question

While writing up a short essay on this fact, I became interested in what happens when you relax some of the rules.

In particular, for the small values I checked on the computer, removing the second rule ("Each brick is offset by 1 stud") appears to result in $4^{n-1}$ towers with $n$ bricks.

I imagine this result exists in the literature, and I was hoping MSE could help me find it. If it hasn't been written down anywhere, I was hoping for insight for how to adapt Bóna's proof into this new setting.

Comment: Connected... and interesting as well, [this document](http://www.numdam.org/article/ITA_1992__26_3_205_0.pdf) in French

Comment: An old MathsSE question interesting for its [references](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1585062)

Comment: @JMP, I included the tag [tag:statistical-mechanics] because the original 1988 paper was a statistical mechanics paper.

Comment: @PeterKagey; I read the tag info : https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/statistical-mechanics/info, and it doesn't seem to match, but good call!

Comment: Does it have to stand up on its own?  If you keep putting them all on one side, it will tip over.

Comment: We can assume the LEGO connections are infinitely strong, including the connection to the ground.

Comment: @PeterKagey might you share the code, or computer program you wrote. Or maybe point to a reference.

Comment: @AntonioHernandezMaquivar, [Here's the Ruby code](https://gist.github.com/peterkagey/72114d458b3789463e27aa5575816ac1) that I used, but it might not be especially clear since it wasn't designed for external consumption.

Comment: For what it's worth, I asked this question in preparation for [my pitch](https://aperiodical.com/2020/05/the-big-lock-down-math-off-match-15/) in The Big Lock-Down Math-Off in The Aperiodical.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your result $4^{n-1}$ is correct. Bóna's proof goes through with a single modification. In the last step that counts the half-pyramids, there is one more option: A bottom brick with a half-pyramid on it whose bottom brick is directly on top of the bottom brick.

Instead of $H\cong(H\times\bullet\times H)+(\bullet\times H)+\bullet$ we get $H\cong(H\times\bullet\times H)+(\bullet\times H)+(\bullet\times H)+\bullet$, thus $H=xH^2+2xH+x$, and then

\begin{eqnarray}
P
&=&
\frac H{(1-H)^2}
\\
&=&
\frac H{-2H + (1+H^2)}
\\
&=&
\frac H{-2H + H\frac{1-2x}x}
\\
&=&
\frac x{1-4x}\;.
\end{eqnarray}